# Title is always displayed even if it is hidden in the Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008, rdlc

I have a problem on additional title that I was displaying inside the **Chart**. My expression did not trigger the behavior of visibility of the title in the chart. Even if the expression satisfy the condition still the **Title** is always shown in the report. What I'd like to do is show only the **Title** if the Chart has data else do not show.

[image]

Here is my expression I used in the **Title**:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox11.Value <> 0, True, False)
```

Thanks in advance to someone that can help me.

Comment: may be check the value of your Textbox11.Value

Comment: try Textbox11.Value.ToString().Length <> 0

Comment: Textbox11.Value has value depending if there's data to be displayed else none. So,  I was wondering what I could miss. I already tried checking it in a textbox to see what is the result. It gives the right result to display it as hidden or not but still no effect after I extract the report.

Comment: try to use my answer `=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox11.Value.ToString().Length <> 0, True, False)`

Answer (score 0):

try this add in Hidden expression.

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox11.Value.ToString().Length > 0, True, False)
```

Comment: Still the same issue. It still show the Title even if the chart has data.

Comment: what's the value of `Textbox11` ?

Comment: It has a value of (113) which has length of 3 and expression of TRUE. so it is expected to hide the title but still display it.

Comment: :( try this `=IIF(Parameters!Textbox11.Value.ToString().Length > 0, True, False)`

Comment: Hi @Ramgy Borja, still the same issue. :( I tried to force the expression to True or False and it works but when I'm using an expression it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my issue using a work around. What I did is in the **Caption** of the **Title** Property, I add an expression which I also used in the expression on the **Hidden** property.

Here is the expression I used:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox11.Value > 0, "", "No Data Found")
```

So, when no records found it will display the message.

[image]

else, it will only display an empty string. It will not display in the chart like it was hidden.

[image]

Hope it helps other which have the same issue with mine.